# Can redux be seen as a pub/sub or observer pattern?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm just trying to get my head around react.js, that being said, I just finished a few tutorials on the web.

I am completely new to redux, which is part of some video tutorials I watched. The more I dive into it, the less it makes sense to me in terms of redux replacing the initial idea of react.js. In react a component has its own state which can be passed down via props, to keep the workflow from top to bottom.

With redux we now try to make the whole application state global and we have to define actions to manipulate that (global) state, so what are these actions other than a "normal" javascript pub/sub or observer pattern? Or maybe I am getting it wrong? - Clarification would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Redux is not supposed to "replace the initial idea of react.js", think of it more like a library to managed shared state between components and to coordinate state mutations.
Redux does use a pub/sub pattern indeed, see the store methods here:
http://redux.js.org/docs/api/Store.html#store-methods
You'll find a `subscribe` method that is used by components to subscribe to changes in the state tree. Normally you don't use store.subscribe directly, as the Redux-React bindings (Redux `connect` basically) do that for you. You can check out the actual implementation here, it's not that complicated to follow (in fact to me that's the main benefit of Redux over other Flux implementations): https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/4.x/src/components/connect.js#L199

That code, apart from subscribing to the changes emitted by the store, also perform some optimisations, such as passing new props to the component (and hence triggering a re-render) only when that's really needed.

Consider also that it's perfectly fine to keep using the components internal state together with Redux. You can use the internal state to store state you don't need/want to share with other components.

You see the need of something like Redux when you have a more complicated application, with top-level components that need to talk to each other (actions) and somehow share some state.

Actions in Redux are by default just POJO (plain old javascript objects), you can think of them as "events" that you often dispatch in response to user-triggered actions (e.g. user clicked on a button), but you're not limited to that, you can dispatch an action from wherever you want. The Redux store listens for these actions and calls the reducers (pure functions) passing the action object you dispatched.

Reducers intercepts all the dispatched actions and they can return a new, updated state for the slice of state they manage.

In this sense, a reducer is a function that processes the actions and updates the state as needed.

In turn, when a reducer updates the state by returning a new copy of the state, connected components (subscribed to the changes in the state) will be passed new props and will re-render to reflect the changes.

Sometimes, dispatching just plain js objects is not enough and you need more control. That becomes clear when you need to perform more complicated logic, for instance when you need to update a counter in the state based on the response from an AJAX call.

With redux-thunk you can dispatch functions as opposed to just plain objects. By dispatching a function, you're effectively implementing the inversion of control pattern in a very simple way. You action becomes a "recipe" described by the function, and not just a simple statement, as with a POJO action.

Why just POJOs supported "out of the box", for actions, why isn't there a base Action class or something? Mainly because there's no need for that. A simple object (considered as a bag for values basically) with a `type` property is all you really need, it's basically the simplest possible interface. You can consider this to be programming against an interface (the action) instead of an implementation.

Why a global state is better, instead of each component managing its own state? Mainly because managing the state is actually the hardest part of a non-trivial js app. By using Redux, you extract all that logic from the UI layer, making it easier to test. In fact, you should ideally be able test all the real "business logic" of a Redux app without even rendering a single component.

Components become "dumber" and "purer" as they just render what they are told to do. "Purer" here means that because they don't hold any state, what you see rendered just depends on the inputs (read "props") at any given point in time, and not by any history, hence "stateless".

Having the state as a single, json serialisable object also makes it easy to debug, to snapshot it and send/restore from a server or local storage.

Comment: `just POJO (plain old javascript objects)` :) I've never actually encountered this term outside of Java. I guess it works but it did confuse me for a few seconds when I read it first.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not a Java developer but I know where the acronym comes from :)

Answer (score 13):

Can't upvote Fabios answer twice and the comments section is to small:

Yes in my view it's like a pub/sub with a convention.

To illustrate how passing down props can be a pain, here's an example.

Let's say you have a component that displays the current logged in user. Your components hierarchy is like a huge tree. Now if you would display that component on a branch starting at the root, and in another branch also starting at the root, each deep deep down in the hierarchy, you would have to pass the user infos from the root component to the leaf nodes on 2 different paths, polluting the props of every components in the way (which aren't related at all to user's infos, but now they need to know).

Comment: @vsync You're misunderstanding how this works, as you assume your individual timer are stateful components. They shouldn't be: the whole point is that each timer state is in the store and your "timers" are just visual representations of each of those sub-states. You would still dispatch a `RESET_ALL_TIMERS` action, and then your reducer react to that event by looping through each of the timers, resetting them. Super simple and easy to test.

Comment: @oligofren I don't think he is misunderstanding how this works. He gave a perfect example of how this is implemented in plain React, with no Redux, i.e. with no action/reducers. You can't dispatch a "RESET_ALL_TIMERS" on plain React. Your example is a Redux example and that's the whole point of his argument (of how Redux improves React development, by allowing to dispatch messages instead of having to heavily rely on "props").

Comment: @DanielLoureiro I think you might misunderstand what I am commenting on. I didn't comment on Mike's answer, but on a comment by @vsync, which has since been deleted. Hence the `@vsync` :)

Comment: Seeing that the original comment to which I responded has been deleted, I might as well just delete my comment, I guess. Seems to add more confusion to the mix as it stands.

Comment: Oh, I see. Sorry about the misunderstanding. I didn't notice the names were different (mike / vsync). I thought you were commenting on Mike's answer and I got confused. Lol